# Scroll the other window in VIM Split

Tags: vim, scroll

How do I scroll the other window in `:vsplit` in VIM? I've looked everywhere, but all websites are talking about how to sync both windows to scroll together. I want to look at one file, edit it, while scrolling the other.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm fairly (ok, quite) certain there's nothing built in to do this, not least of all because it only makes sense when there are exactly two windows. For that specific case, however, you can use a mapping. Put these in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
nmap <a-j> <c-w>w<c-e><c-w>w
nmap <a-k> <c-w>w<c-y><c-w>w
```

This will make <kbd>Alt+J</kbd> scroll down and <kbd>Alt+K</kbd> up, you can change those as you like.  If you want it to work with more windows, you'll have to write a script.

Answer (score 0):

```
" SCROLLING FOR OTHER SPLIT WINDOWS (JUST 2 WINDOWS)    
nmap <M-j> <c-w>w<c-e><c-w>wh " Scroll down one line other pane    
nmap <M-k> <c-w>w<c-y><c-w>wh " Scroll up one line other pane    
nmap <M-d> <c-w>w<c-d><c-w>wh " Scroll down half screen other pane    
nmap <M-u> <c-w>w<c-u><c-w>wh " Scroll up half screen  other pane    
nmap <M-f> <c-w>w<c-f><c-w>wh " Scroll down one screen other pane    
nmap <M-b> <c-w>w<c-b><c-w>wh " Scroll up one screen other pane
```

`<M>` is Meta, Opt, or Alt key. When I tested the shortcut, my cursor in the current window go forward 1 character. So I ended mapping the bindings with `h`. But these work whenever you don't reach the first or last line of your other pane or the cursor will just switch to your current pane then start scrolling.